# Using a string with switch/case

Tags: c, string, arduino, switch-statement

Right now, I have the following switch-case, built using an enum representing some text.

```
    String inputMessage = Serial.readString();    //Input is either TEXT_1 or TEXT_2.
    enum Messages {
        TEXT_1, TEXT_2
    };
    enum Messages currentMessage = TEXT_2;
    switch (currentMessage) {
      case TEXT_1: 
        Serial.println("RESPONSE_1");
        break;
      case TEXT_2: 
        Serial.println("RESPONSE_2");
        break;
      default:
        break;
```

I am trying to get to a point where the contents of a String (this is Arduino C code), inputMessage, which will be TEXT_1 or TEXT_2, to control currentMessage, which will control the switch-case. I would like to avoid an if-else stack if possible (thus, the switch-case attempt) since I do intend to scale up the number of TEXT to a much higher number in the future.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: You can just add more `case` clauses or use an array for the messages... what is your question?

Comment: If the values of `TEXT_1` and `TEXT_2` are `0`, `1` etc you can index an array of strings or string pointers and avoid `if` and `switch`. With `char *msg[] = { "RESPONSE_1", "RESPONSE_2" };` for example and `Serial.println(msg[currentMessage]);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Could you elaborate? I'm afraid I don't quite follow.

Comment: What is the type of `TEXT_1` and `TEXT_2`?

Comment: What's more to say? You can have an array of strings, indexed by their reference ID. `TEXT_1` etc has a value of `0`, etc.

Comment: I think @WeatherVane means something like https://ideone.com/WMnmJn

Comment: It is unclear from the question whether `TEXT_1` is an integer or a string. First it is commented as a message from serial, then it is defined as `enum`. It would be clearer if you showed an actual message, and what you want to do with it, but the serial input in the given code is unrelated to what follows.

Comment: @WeatherVane `TEXT_1` cannot be a string as it is used in enum declaration.

Comment: @0___________ that is exactly why I asked for clarification. it is also described as a string input from serial. See the first line of of the code, which has a comment. Is this a descriptive string or a numeric string (which can be conveted to an integer)?

Comment: Re “much higher number in the future”: Store the strings in a sorted array and use `bsearch` to look up the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum` is just an integer. It is not a string.

you need to have a if/else ladder with string comparison functions as you cant have a string as a control expression of the `switch/case`. Only integers are allowed

Comment: Missed opportunity with this 'closed'... OP mentioned "a much higher number in the future"... An "if/else tree" might, at least, be somewhat better than the inevitable presumed linear search of the space.